# Crash on ListView.removeFooterView(View)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting crash reports on

```
 android.widget.ListView  lv;  lv.removeFooterView(v)
```

The error is null pointer exception.  I check that listView itself is not null.  What causes this?  Is it necessary to make sure the view to be removed is not null? Is that enough or do I first need to also check that the footer view actually has been added?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.ListView.removeFooterView(ListView.java:374)
```

It seems to me this method should be robust enough not to crash!  Why does it not just return false if it cannot remove the view?

PS.  I would like to know if anyone else has seen this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately you don't mention what Android version the error reports are coming from. However, looking at the source code, Android 2.1-update1 seems like a good candidate.

I'll just copy in the whole method to make things clear:

```
public boolean removeFooterView(View v) {
    if (mFooterViewInfos.size() > 0) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (((HeaderViewListAdapter) mAdapter).removeFooter(v)) { // <- line 274
            mDataSetObserver.onChanged();
            result = true;
        }
        removeFixedViewInfo(v, mFooterViewInfos);
        return result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now compare above `removeFooterView(...)` method with the implementation of a more recent platform:

```
public boolean removeFooterView(View v) {
    if (mFooterViewInfos.size() > 0) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (mAdapter != null && ((HeaderViewListAdapter) mAdapter).removeFooter(v)) {
            if (mDataSetObserver != null) {
                mDataSetObserver.onChanged();
            }
            result = true;
        }
        removeFixedViewInfo(v, mFooterViewInfos);
        return result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, the've added in a couple of extra checks for certain members not being `null`. That would suggest that the first method will indeed fail on line 274 if `mAdapter == null`, whereas that wouldn't cause a crash with the newer implementation.

To work around it, all you probably need to do is add something like `lv.getAdapter() != null` before trying to remove the footer view.

Comment: What is the policy for adding footers.  I am getting this error again on FROYO and the listView.getFooterCount() > 0.

Comment: I had the possibility to call removeFooter() after I set the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

IF you check out the documentation you will notice that that is actually the case:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#removeFooterView%28android.view.View%29)

> Returns
>
> true if the view was removed, false if the view was not a footer view

So you should add a null check for both the view and the listView or if this is an exceptional state (happens very rarely then wrap it in an exception block).

Comment: Wrapping a null pointer in an exception block will still crash!

Comment: The documentation does not indicate that trying to remove a null view will crash your application.

Comment: I'm not convinced that removing a null view will crash the app.  I think it might be the null adapter.