# NPE while accessing a ListView Activity

Tags: android, android-listview

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.ListView.removeFooterView(ListView.java:432)
at com.app.mobileapp.MainActivity$getValues.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:666)
```

**Line 666:**

```
listView.removeFooterView(footerView);
```

But definitely the **ListView** and the **FooterView** both are created well. Because I could set the footer to the listview just before the **line 666**:

```
listView.addFooterView(footerView);

mAdapter = new mainAdapter(MainActivity.this, item_list, listView);

if (result.equals("empty")) {
    ((TextView) footerView.findViewById(R.id.footer))
        .setText("No values");
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
} else if (result.equals("success")) {
    listView.removeFooterView(footerView);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Also the case of **"empty"** works fine. And the Footer View shows **"No values"**. But crashes for the **"success"** case.

> This works fine on **Android 4.0 +** but crashes on **2.3.6**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From:**

[Crash on ListView.removeFooterView(View)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126422/crash-on-listview-removefooterviewview)

Its the problem with Android version of public `boolean removeFooterView(View v)` on 2.3.6, which doesn't check if the adapter is already set to the ListView or not.

**So, all I had to do is check:**

```
listView.getAdapter() != null;
```

before removing the **footerView**.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you are trying to remove the footer view before adding it to the list view in case of success . that's why you are getting NPE .

```
 listView.addFooterView(footerView);

mAdapter = new mainAdapter(MainActivity.this, item_list, listView);

if (result.equals("empty")) {
    ((TextView) footerView.findViewById(R.id.footer))
        .setText("No values");
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
} else if (result.equals("success")) {

    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    listView.removeFooterView(footerView);
}
```

Try This Code : best of luck

Comment: I have this line `listView.addFooterView(footerView);` above the `if clause` in my code too.

Comment: the problem is that listView.removeFooterView(footerView); works on runtime . have you got my point of changing the positionj for listView.removeFooterView(footerView); in above code

Answer (score 0):

it's not quite an answer to how to remove the footer view , but i have 2 possible solutions:

1.just a tip for this specific case: instead of adding and removing right away, why not checking if you need to add and only then add, instead? example:

> ```
> mAdapter = new mainAdapter(MainActivity.this, item_list, listView);
> if ("empty".equals(result)) {
>     ((TextView) footerView.findViewById(R.id.footer))
>         .setText("No values");
>     listView.addFooterView(footerView);
>     listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
> } else if ("success".equals(result))
>     listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
> ```

2.if the code doesn't work for old versions of android, you could have the footer view to be a container (FrameLayout for example) of the real content of the footerView, and let it stay forever. if it needs to be filled with content , fill it, and if not, don't.